# Splitting graphs into disjoint sets by removal of edges

Tags: graph-theory

You have to split the graph into two disjoint sets such that every vertex in a set has only one vertex connected to it from the another set .That is,after doing the operation,you'll have all the vertex degree from both the set as 1.You are allowed to delete the edges,to make the graph behave in this way.

For example: 
If a graph has 4 vertices and 6 edges as

1-2

1-3

1-4

2-3

2-4

3-4,

We can split it into two sets,{1,2} and {3,4} by deleting all the other edges.

Another example:

1-2

2-3

(Cannot be splitted)

Here you cannot split even after deleting any number of edges.

I'm trying this problem from today morning using several methods.I tried bipartite matching,but didn't work.If you want my code which failed,i can provide.

Thanks.

If the question is not clear,i can explain it better if required.

Comment: So you're looking for a perfect matching?

Comment: No i guess.I'm not sure what perfect matching is.What i require is,given a graph with edge details,you have to say whether it is possible to make the degree of each vertex of the graph 1(one) by deleting some edges ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're looking for what is called a *perfect matching*. This a very well-studied problem so you should have no trouble finding more information via Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of a [perfect matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) (as mentioned in the comments), also known as a 1-factor.  It's a [1-regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph) [spanning subgraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory#Subgraphs).

To have a 1-factor a graph must have an even number of vertices.  In cases where a graph has an odd number of vertices, we talk about "near 1-factors".

[Tutte's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_theorem) gives necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of a perfect matching:

> A graph, $G = (V, E)$, has a perfect matching if and only if for every subset $U$ of $V$, the subgraph induced by $V-U$ has at most $|U|$ connected components with an odd number of vertices.